# What is $post->pre_post_content exactly?

Tags: posts, post-content

We have an issue with getting updated data for editing from one of our posts in our site and i found this piece of code to get the content of the post

```
$post->pre_post_content
```

instead of something like

```
$post->post_content
```

the content of `pre_post_content` seems to be holding data from one of the older revisions of the post instead of the more updated content in `post_content`. It also has shortcode blocks stripped from it which is still present in `post_content`.

What is this exactly? I couldn't find any info about this.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing. [`pre_post_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_post_field/) is a *filter* that allows you to filter the result of [sanitize_post_field()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_post_field/) for the `post_content` field of posts. But the standard [`WP_Post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/) class, which `$post` usually is, does not have a `pre_post_content` field.

If `$post` on your site has such a field, then it's likely being added by a plugin, but a web search of `$post->pre_post_content` turned up nothing, so I'm not sure where you got it from.

Comment: thank you. i will check my site and look for this one.